# Failure of twice-differentiation with numDeriv R package

Tags: r, numerical-methods, derivative

How would you explain this failure of numerical twice-differentiation with the `numDeriv` package ?

Below is a function `Y` and its first derivative `dY`.

```
Y <- function(x, A=1, B=1, a=1){
  A*cos(a*x) + B*sin(a*x) - x/2/a*cos(a*x)
}
dY <- function(x, A=1, B=1, a=1){
  -a*A*sin(a*x) + a*B*cos(a*x) - cos(a*x)/2/a + x/2/a*sin(a*x)
}
```

And below is a successful illustration of the `grad` function of the `numDeriv` package:

```
library(numDeriv)
x <- c(0.2,0.4,0.6)
grad(Y, x)
## [1] 0.31123 0.14900 0.01742
dY(x)
## [1] 0.31123 0.14900 0.01742
```

Twice-differentiation below works fine too:

```
dYnum <- function(x) grad(Y, x)
d2Ynum <- function(x) grad(dYnum, x)
d2Ynum(x)
## [1] -0.8820 -0.7368 -0.5777
grad(dY, x)
## [1] -0.8821 -0.7368 -0.5777
```

But when replacing `Y` with a sharp approximate, twice-differientation fails:

```
xx <- seq(0.01, 0.99, by=0.01)
Yapprox <- approxfun(xx, Y(xx))
dYnum <- function(x) grad(Yapprox, x)
dYnum(x) # first-order derivative is OK
## [1] 0.31124 0.14901 0.01743
d2Ynum <- function(x) grad(dYnum, x)
d2Ynum(x) # not the good result
## [1] -2698 -1127  -589
grad(dY, x)  # this is the good result
## [1] -0.8821 -0.7368 -0.5777
```

However when replacing `dYnum` with an approximate, it works again:

```
xx <- seq(0.1, 0.9, by=0.01)
dYnumapprox <- approxfun(xx, dYnum(xx)) # approxfun(xx, grad(Yapprox, xx))
d2Ynum_ <- function(x) grad(dYnumapprox, x)
d2Ynum_(x) 
## [1] -0.8820 -0.7368 -0.5777
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the inner derivative in the last term. The a in the denominator cancels with the inner derivative. So it should be

```
  -a*A*sin(a*x) + a*B*cos(a*x) - cos(a*x)/2/a + x/2*sin(a*x)
```

---

As for the error, I would suspect that the culprit is the approximation. Depending on the type of the approximation, the error between the sample points in the function values can be arbitrarily large, which only magnifies when computing derivatives. You might get better results by using far less sample points, 6 instead of 99.

---

**RTFM**: Per [R-manual `approxfun`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/approxfun.html) only provides piecewise constant or linear approximations. Both are not differentiable. This means that the derivative of the piecewise linear approximation is piecewise constant with jumps and the second derivative is piecewise zero with delta peaks at the sample points. Re-interpolating the first derivative via a piecewise linear function will, while not the most mathematical procedure, lead back to reasonable results.

Use [R-manual `splinefun`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/splinefun.html) to get an interpolating function that actually is twice differentiable.

Comment: Thank you for pointing the error in the derivative. It is effectless here because of `a=1`.

Comment: Can you detail what `approxfun` is doing?

Comment: Found documentation. What you are doing is fundamentally bad to wrong, or in other words, flawed.

Comment: Right, this was a confusion between `approxfun` and `splinefun`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you expect: not for nothing is numerical differentiation called "error magnification" . The fact that your `dYnum` values are not identical to the non-approxfun values should be a huge red flag to warn you that the data you're feeding to your second numerical differentiation has got noise in it.   the `grad` (or any other numerical differentiator) function then dutifully differentiates the high-frequency components caused by the noise in the data.

Comment: What do you call the "noise" in this example ?

Comment: 31123 vs. 31124,  14900 vs. 14901 .

Comment: Ok but this is small "noise", and why there is such an impact on the second derivative ? Why does it work with `dYnumapprox` which is not less "noisy" ?